# pointer-events:none prevents title attribute

Tags: html, css

I am having an anchor tag, which should not be clicked so i have added pointer events none.i have a title attribute on the anchor tag need to be shown while hovering. **pointer-event:none** prevents the **title** tag from showing up.Is there a way to have both pointer-events:none and title showing up.

```css
a{
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" title="Some Sample Title"> Sample Link </a>
```

Comment: `title` is a *pointer event*, @codegeek. It's displayed when your cursor hovers the element. What do you expect `title` attribute to do when you specify `pointer-events:none`? You can fix your problem  using onclick: `<a href title="Some Sample Title" onclick="javascript:void(0);">`. Or, alternatively, `onclick="javascript:function(e){e.preventDefault()}"`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No, `pointer-events: none` is pretty encompassing in that any eventType that is associated with the mouse. You could wrap a `<span>` around the anchor and assign the `title` to that instead. It's ugly but valid.

### Demo

```css
a {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<span title='I am wrapped around this anchor'>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" title="Some Sample Title">Sample Link</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

According to: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/, I think `pointer-event` has a very specific use.

If you want interact with the mouse cursor you have `cursor` attribut and in your case:

```css
a:hover{
  cursor:default;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" title="Some Sample Title"> Sample Link </a>
```

Comment: This helps me a bit but allows clicking.but i have added jquery code to avoid clicking of this link

Comment: @codegeek Maybe you should change the accepted answer, because this is not the right solution for this.